# Add new winforms into a big application after shipping to the customer

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, exe

Lets assume that we have developed and shipped an application to many customers. We would like to add new screens to that application without removing and re-installing from customers computers the entire application. We just want to send a DLL or an EXE file to the customer, then they will put that file and place it to application folder. Then application will find and recognize that DLL or EXE and let user use that `WinForm`?

How can I do that? Would you please give me an idea?

Comment: You have already shipped a compiled exe so your existing program has no idea you wish to extend it, and therefore does not know how it would

Comment: MEF, MEF and more MEF.... Did I mention MEF? However if your application does not already do MEF you will have to reinstall it everywhere.

Comment: I said "Lets assume..." I havent shipped it yet, and I want to prepare my application for future additions of winforms. any ideas?

Comment: @HighCore thanks for the clue. I am googling now

Comment: @ayilmaz - MEF is a good framework for creating extensible programs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered. Search for `[c#] plugin architecture` here, or `csharp plugin architecture` on Google. Once you have done some research into that, you can come back and ask specific questions about problems you encounter implementing it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

professional and complete solution is [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) if you want something simple, you could use something like Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath) and iterate types in it. check for if the type is derived from System.Windows.Forms.Form (you should use typeof(Form).IsAssignableFrom(loadedType))

Answer (score 1):

This problem is why web-applications are so popular.  A single install for everyone.  Change without re-installing in multiple locations.

This problem is why SAAS exists.  The true solution to this problem is get off the winform-gui model.

Think bigger!

Comment: I agree with getting rid of dinosaur winforms, hoewever a web application doesn't hold a candle when compared to a WPF application. In order to achieve the responsiveness and interactivity levels of a WPF application, a web application requires a ton of horrible javascript hacks, which are a horrible developer experience when compared to the beauty of XAML and MVVM. Web applications DO have a TON of good things, but they can never replace a well designed desktop app.